# pandas pivot table with unique values of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have df with some string values.

```
so = pd.DataFrame({
"col1": ["row0", "row1", "row2"],
"col2": ["A", "B", "C"],
"col3": ["A", "A", "B"],
"col4":  ["B", "A", "B"],
})
```

I need to create pivot table where:

1. **index** is values from column "col1"
2. **columns** are unique values from columns ['col2':'col4']
3. **values** at the intersection are count of column name matches for every row

For my example, the answer should be:

[image]

Please help... thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`melt` and `crosstab`:

```
df2 = so.melt('col1')
pd.crosstab(df2['col1'], df2['value'])
```

or `melt` and `groupby.count`:

```
so.melt('col1').groupby(['col1', 'value']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

output:

```
value  A  B  C
col1          
row0   2  1  0
row1   2  1  0
row2   0  2  1
```

*NB. for the exact output, use `.reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)`*

Comment: melt and groupby seems good for me. But what if i want to use as `index` first two columns?
`melt('col1', 'col2')` works as expected, but how i need to write `groupby`? `groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'value'])` doesn't work. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: There is no more `col2` after `melt`, check the output ;) If you want to use `col2` both as grouper and value you need to duplicate it.

Comment: I mean, what of I need to save `'col1', 'col2'` as index and count unique values only for columns `'col3','col4'`? Maybe its easer for me to understand with melt&crosstab:

`df2 = so.melt(['col1','col2']) ###works as i expect###
pd.crosstab(df2[?], df2['value']) ###can't understand###`

Comment: Maybe you should open a follow up question with all details?

Comment: Hooraaaay, I did it, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
df.melt('col1').pivot_table(index='col1', columns='value', aggfunc=(lambda x: int(x.size))  ).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

```
    col1    variable
value       A         B     C
0   row0    2.0     1.0     0.0
1   row1    2.0     1.0     0.0
2   row2    0.0     2.0     1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It works for me too!
Can you please explain to me the mechanics of the lambda in this case? I can't figure out how the calculations happen :(

Comment: Pivot is resulting in multiple values for row/column (cell) as a list, aggfunc here is a lambda function that takes the size of this list and return the count. Hope it helps

Comment: Yep, I get it. Thank you for the explanation!